# Using Smarty Templates to send emails

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have a table named `Template` which I set my messages to send them via mail, I need php variables to input into.

My question is: can I use Smarty to edit my messages (they are in HTML code) after retrieving them from the table?

For example, I have:

```
$message = getMsgFromTable(Template);
```

`$message` has the type Text which contains php variables. Can I use Smarty to fill this variable like this?

```
$message = setVariableValueBySmarty($message);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smarty can fetch the template and return its output instead of displaying it.
The `fetch()` method does this, and that's what you need:

> http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.fetch.tpl

There's also a paragraph in documentation that tell you how to use it to send mails :)

> http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.fetch.tpl#id627712

If you need to **create template** from the database (stored as string), take a look at this:

> http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl

Comment: Thank you so much lorenzo-s ;)

Comment: Sorry but I thought that I can accept more than one answer ;)

Comment: *When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.* (from **[How to ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)**)

Comment: Ok :p
I use this code :
$smarty->assign('foo','value');
$template_string = 'display {$foo} here';
$smarty->display('string:'.$template_string);
so how could I get the result :s !! 
is this true : $message = $smarty->display('string:'.$template_string);
???

Comment: @BFK Yes, I think it's right. Assign all variables with `assign()` (as usual with Smarty), then load the template from the database and assign it to `$template_string`, finally use `$message = $smarty->display('string:'.$template_string);`.

Answer (score 1):

see @lorenzo-s and:

If your DB-stored templates contain "PHP variables" in the form `<?php echo $foo; ?>` (or similar, doesn't matter), you might want to use a [prefilter](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.prefilters.tpl) to convert `<?php echo $foo; ?>` to `{$foo}` so you can use Smarty's assign() method to fill templates with your data.